# Installed git on OS X; What should I add to my PATH?

Tags: git, macos, version-control

I just installed git 1.6.4.4 after downloading a DMG package from [here](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount).

I now have `/usr/local/git`. But it isn't in my PATH. So I need to add it.

My question is, should I add just `/usr/local/git/bin`, or do I also need to add one or more of these other directories?

```
$ cd /usr/local/git/
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 joefleen  wheel  102 Sep 17 12:22 Library
drwxr-xr-x  9 root      wheel  306 Sep 27 11:09 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      wheel  102 Sep 17 12:22 contrib
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      wheel  102 Sep 17 12:22 lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      wheel  102 Sep 17 12:22 libexec
drwxr-xr-x  6 root      wheel  204 Sep 17 12:22 share
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all you need to add is `/usr/local/git/bin`. You can test this by running it directly:

```
/usr/local/git/bin/git
```

and see whether it works.

Comment: I edited the path in the answer so it reflects what the DMG put on my system. I think that's what Greg meant.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is what Greg says above. However, in that DMG there is a shell script for updating your PATH for non-terminal programs. That is also worth running.

It simply adds /usr/local/git/bin to your .MacOSX/environment.plist

Comment: To clarify. If you want git accessible from programs started from a Terminal e,g command line got then add /usr/local/got/bin to the path in your shell else if wanted from other apps e.g. from Finder then you meed to add it to your .MacOSX/environment.plist

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned updating your PATH environment variable, but you may also want to update your MANPATH variable as well to get access to the man pages.

Add `/usr/local/git/share/man` to it.